# Остановка объекат

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

делаю анимацию вращения с кнопки запускается, но стрелка возвращается на свое начальное положение, как оставить ее там где она остановилась?
Код https://yadi.sk/d/4h6Z2DlcuAK3u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте эти две строки в метод `func rotateLayer(currentLayer:CALayer){}`:

```
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
```